# ordering images horizontally but not on the same level

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float

I have the following div:

```
<div id="features">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li class="feature-1"><a href="#"><img      src="img/black/blackMainImg.jpg" height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <li class="feature-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/blue/blueMainImg.jpg" height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <li class="feature-3"><a href="#"><img src="img/green/greenMainImg.jpg" height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <li class="feature-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/red/redMainImg.jpg" height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <li class="feature-5"><a href="#"><img src="img/yellow/yellowMainImg.jpg"height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and I want that the images will be at the same size but be in different levels 
I cant upload photo but I attaching a link for a page that is a very good example of what I mean to
http://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/760?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fall%2F32&bookName=new-ecom&galleryDocIndex=0&category=all&metaSiteId=

Comment: Custom margins on the pictures you want moved around? Then a media query for small devices?

Comment: use `margin` to achieve.

Comment: Note the css properties used in your example: position: absolute; top: 101px; try using same for your feature-xx class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is one way to do it, if I got your question right.**

```css
.wrapper ul {
   display: flex;
  }
.wrapper ul li {
   margin: 10px;
   list-style: none;
  }
.wrapper ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-top: 50px !important;
  }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li class="feature-1"><a href="#"><img      src="img/black/blackMainImg.jpg" height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <li class="feature-2"><a href="#"><img src="img/blue/blueMainImg.jpg" height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <li class="feature-3"><a href="#"><img src="img/green/greenMainImg.jpg" height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <li class="feature-4"><a href="#"><img src="img/red/redMainImg.jpg" height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <li class="feature-5"><a href="#"><img src="img/yellow/yellowMainImg.jpg"height="400px" width="180px"></a></li>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve it like this:

```
.wrapper li {
    float: left; /* Puts them on the same row. */
    margin: 10px; /* Some space around them. */
    list-style: none; /* Remove the bullet point. */
}

/* Individual top margins for the different list items. */
li.feature-1 { margin-top: 20px; }
li.feature-2 { margin-top: 40px; }
li.feature-3 { margin-top:  0px; }
/* ...and so on... */
```

You could also use the [`nth-child()`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) pseudo-selector as suggested in other answers, but then it will not work in IE 8 and below (not a big problem, but still).

Answer (score 0):

I've created something similar but without the images as I do not have them

https://jsfiddle.net/cjqzpb7p/

```
<div id="features">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li class="feature-1"><a href="#">Hi</a></li>
            <li class="feature-2"><a href="#">Block</a></li>
            <li class="feature-3"><a href="#">Blockz</a></li>
            <li class="feature-4"><a href="#">Blocks</a></li>
            <li class="feature-5"><a href="#">Blockx</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


#features li {
   height: 400px;
   background: red;
   width: 180px;
   display: block;
   list-style-type: none;
   float: left;

   &:nth-child(2n+2) {
      margin: 50px 20px 0 20px;
   }
}
```

Markup CSS done in SASS